# sum two column using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to sum two column using linq, is this possible?

```
var dat1 = from b in dt1.AsEnumerable()
    select new
    {
        fLogin2 = b.Field<Decimal>("Login"),
        fBalance2 = b.Field<Decimal>("Balance"),
        fFloatingPNL2 = b.Field<Decimal>("FloatingPNL"),
        fEquity1 = (fBalance2 + fFloatingPNL2)
    };
```

Comment: Please, do not link to images with code but put it in the question.

Comment: @PeterBons The post was edited accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fBalance2` does not exist in the context you are using it. So, you have two options:

1) Using `let`:

```
from b in dt1.AsEnumerable()
    let balance = b.Field<decimal>("Balance")
    let floatingPNL = b.Field<decimal>("FloatingPNL")
    select new
    {
        fLogin2 = b.Field<Decimal>("Login"),
        fBalance2 = balance,
        fFloatingPNL2 = floatingPNL,
        fEquity1 = (balance + floatingPNL)
    };
```

2) Or duplicate the expression:

```
var dat1 = from b in dt1.AsEnumerable()
    select new
    {
        fLogin2 = b.Field<Decimal>("Login"),
        fBalance2 = b.Field<Decimal>("Balance"),
        fFloatingPNL2 = b.Field<Decimal>("FloatingPNL"),
        fEquity1 = (b.Field<Decimal>("Balance") + b.Field<Decimal>("FloatingPNL"))
    };
```

Comment: i did it works but now i have error on fLogin2 ->System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Comment: @GiorgiVanGoGh Is `Login` a `Decimal`? That sounds very weird

Comment: now i edit my code that was not neither decimal nor Decimal that was int xDD thank you